# SCons Ignore function not working

Tags: scons

I have some log files generated after each file is compiled.

I am making SCons aware of these files by using an emitter attached to the builder that I'm using to compile that file.

Unfortunately, because I am deleting the empty log files after each build SCons recompiles the source files because the log files are missing.

I would like to ignore these 'side effect' files using SCons Ignore function.

In my emitter I am doing something like this:

```
def compiler_emitter(target, source, env):
target.append(env.File(source[0].name.split('.')[0] + env['ERRSUFFIX']))    
env.Ignore(source[0], target[1])    
return target, source
```

As a note I always pass only one file to my builder.

In my case Ignore function is not working.

What will be the best approach to solve this problem in a 'SCons way' ?

Comment: I don't understand why you first add the additional log/error files in your Emitter, but then want to "ignore" them. If they aren't important for your build, just don't tell the Emitter about them. That would be my approach at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using env.SideEffect() instead of Ignore:

> **SideEffect(side_effect, target) , env.SideEffect(side_effect, target)**
>
> Declares side_effect as a side effect of building target. Both
>   side_effect and target can be a list, a file name, or a node. A side
>   effect is a target file that is created or updated as a side effect of
>   building other targets. For example, a Windows PDB file is created as
>   a side effect of building the .obj files for a static library, and
>   various log files are created updated as side effects of various TeX
>   commands. If a target is a side effect of multiple build commands,
>   scons will ensure that only one set of commands is executed at a time.
>   Consequently, you only need to use this method for side-effect targets
>   that are built as a result of multiple build commands.
>
> Because multiple build commands may update the same side effect file,
>   by default the side_effect target is not automatically removed when
>   the target is removed by the -c option. (Note, however, that the
>   side_effect might be removed as part of cleaning the directory in
>   which it lives.) If you want to make sure the side_effect is cleaned
>   whenever a specific target is cleaned, you must specify this
>   explicitly with the Clean or env.Clean function.

http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html